# Jquery li element id

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using a jquery contextmenu plugin for right click menus which I am trying to add to each li element of an unordered list with the ID mailbox.  The code I have is:

```
    $("#mailbox > li").contextMenu('myMenu1', {
      bindings: {
    'open': function(t) {
      alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Open');
    }
    //CODE SNIPPED
    });
```

My assumption is that this should alert the id of the list element that the contextMenu was called from, however it is returning an empty string.  Am I accessing/assigning these correctly?

t is an object HTMLLIElement in the context above by the way.

Cheers,
Gazler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `"#mailbox li"` as your selector. the reason is that `#mailbox` doesn't have any children of `li`

`element > subelement` is for direct children of the element only.  in this case, the direct child of `#mailbox` would probably be `ul` and not `li` which would be a grand child.  `element subelement` selects all descendants, not just the direct children.

check it out here: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild
and here: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant

Comment: Thanks a lot, a highly simple fix.  Could you explain what the "#element > subelement" selector does?